# Filter on date not working in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter

Given the data to filter:

```
$scope.friends = [
    { "name": 'John',    "phone": '555-1212',    "age": 10, "name-phone-age":now.setMinutes(now.getMinutes() + 30) },
    { "name": 'Mary',    "phone": '555-9876',    "age": 19, "name-phone-age":now.setMinutes(now.getMinutes() + 30) },
    { "name": 'Mike',    "phone": '555-4321',    "age": 21, "name-phone-age":now.setMinutes(now.getMinutes() + 30) },
    { "name": 'Adam',    "phone": '555-5678',    "age": 35, "name-phone-age":now.setMinutes(now.getMinutes() + 30) },
    { "name": 'Julie',   "phone": '555-8765',    "age": 29, "name-phone-age":now.setMinutes(now.getMinutes() + 30) }
  ];
```

Filter on any field using the search input box works except the DATE field;

For example

```
Search : John
Name    Phone Number    Age Some_Random_Date_Time

John    555-1212    10  2014-08-27 20:24:40 540
```

and Search for string 2014 which is part of [output data](http://plnkr.co/edit/r6RerZq2eE0igLQsrxQc?p=preview) as shown, returns with empty result

```
Name    Phone Number    Age Some Random Date Time
John    555-1212    10  2014-08-27 20:24:40 540
Mary    555-9876    19  2014-08-27 20:54:40 540
Mike    555-4321    21  2014-08-27 21:24:40 540
Adam    555-5678    35  2014-08-27 21:54:40 540
Julie   555-8765    29  2014-08-27 22:24:40 540


 Search : 2014
    Name    Phone Number    Age Some_Random_Date_Time
```

[EXAMPLE LINK](http://plnkr.co/edit/r6RerZq2eE0igLQsrxQc?p=preview)

Comment: That is because in your actual data date is not in that format. You are just displaying based on date format filter it does not modify underlying data

Comment: @PSL : If I need to search based on whats is seen on the output window  how do I do it? Write any custom filter?

Comment: Yes either that or add one more property in your friend object to display the formatted date.., which would be more appropriate

Comment: Like this http://plnkr.co/edit/6zchAL?p=preview

Comment: beat me to it. Here's an ES3 friendly variation though http://plnkr.co/edit/25awSlFG5Jkc2WX5pkE9?p=preview . ...which is exactly the same as PSLs answer

Comment: @rob yeah, i used `angular.forEach` itself in my answer as well... But one thing is that in your view you dont need to again do a format filter unwantedly since it has already been updated in the model and this is a display only data, hence...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Search Filter on date* actually works fine. Issue is with your data. Filter works on the data being bound to it. In your example only your display uses a date format filter to display the date in a specific format. If you use search filter it works on the list it is iterated upon (and  remember date format filter does not update the underlying model), So either create a custom filter which can handle date in a formatter manner. But in your case since you need to have the formatted date displayed, i would just format the date in the model itself.

```
  //Add a new property or update the existing property, here i am adding a new one.
  //Or just use friends.forEach
  angular.forEach(friends, function(friend){
     friend.formattedDate = $filter('date')(friend['name-phone-age'],'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss');
  }) ;

   $scope.friends = friends;
```

And now remove the unwanted filter from the view, instead use this field.

```
 <td>{{friend.formattedDate}}</td>
```

**[Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/di1xCi?p=preview)**